# How to run testcafe via node

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have theses two commands I use when testing with testcafe

```
set SELENIUM_SERVER=http://xxx:4447/wd/hub
testcafe selenium:"internet explorer" Test.js
```

How can i rewrite this to run it via node and test runner? I.e. I would like to write something like this:

```
set SELENIUM_SERVER=http://xxx:4447/wd/hub
node tRunner.js selenium:"internet explorer"
```

Cannot figure out what the correct order is when using node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a TestCafe nodejs application and use TestCafe's API to execute your tests.

For instance, your application may look as follows:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        return runner
            .src('Test.js')
            .browsers('selenium:"internet explorer"')
            .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Learn more about TestCafe API in its documentation: [Programming Interface](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/).

Comment: I recommend that you check out the following topic where you can learn how to test in [headless mode](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/testing-in-headless-mode.html). In short, if you use a browser's path, your argument should consist of three parts.